# Android Get length of highlighted text in TextView

Tags: android, textview

I'm doing an app which has a TextView and that's clickable. When clicked it allows user to select certain words or the whole sentence or paragraph. I got the part of selecting and highlighting the text, the problem is I want to have a different colour for the highlight and save the highlighted text to db so the next time the user would check it, he/she will see the highlighted text.

So far this is what I've tried:

```
 tv.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

            int startSelection = tv.getSelectionStart();
            int endSelection = tv.getSelectionEnd();
            String selectedText = tv.getText().toString().substring(startSelection, endSelection);

            Log.e("TEXT", "" + selectedText);

            SpannableString spannable = new SpannableString(tv.getText().toString());

            //Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(tv.getText().toString());
            spannable.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), startSelection, endSelection, 0);

            //tv.setSelection(startSelection, endSelection);
            tv.setText(spannable); 

            return true;
        }

    });
```

**layout.xml:**

```
<TextView
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/tvOrdinanceTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textIsSelectable="true" />
```

Any ideas or workaround? I would gladly appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: So what are your actual results?

Comment: @vokilam I can't get the highlighted text so to store them on table

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Do you want the highlight to be a different color? A different color for each word? Do you want the text to be a different color? Not clear.

Comment: @EranGoldin I want different colour for the highlighted text not for each word, I want to do like YouVersion's bookmark/highlight.

Comment: Use a `TextAppearanceSpan`.

Comment: @EranGoldin can you show some sample codes to do that? Thanks.

Comment: Sure. Adding an answer.

Answer (score 0):

To change text color, use a `ForegroundColorSpan`:

```
spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), startSelection, endSelection, 0);
```

To keep your text color but change the selected text color, use a selector:
Define an xml for it under drawable -- text_color_selector.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/red" />
    <item android:color="@color/black" />
</selector>
```

And use that selector when styling the TextView in your layout XML:

```
android:textColor="@drawable/text_color_selector"
```

If you want to save the selected text get it by doing:

```
String selectedText = v.getText().toString().substring(startSelection, endSelection);
```

Comment: how do you get the startSelection and endSelection?

Comment: Yes I tried doing that but the selection/highlight colour isn't changing

Comment: Now I completely understand. You need a selector for that. Updated my answer to incorporate that.

Comment: How to do that using selector?

Comment: I updated my answer three hours ago to incorporate the selector. Don't forget to accept it if it solves your problem.

Comment: Hi, I'm gettig StringOutOfBoundsException in this line: String selectedText = tv.getText().toString().substring(startSelection, endSelection);

Comment: Yes, i tried but it's still throwing the same exception